# Where/How to start?

Tags: image-classification, image-recognition

I want to create an application that recognises diseases from images, I know this require databases of images and image segmentation but where do I start? What should I start learning? I know nothing about data science but I want to learn. I am familiar with language like C, C#, Python3, Java. As a beginner myself I think many people would be interested to know how to begin and what to do.

Comment: It's because there's no accurate answer to this question , there are many answers/posts if someone searches and it completely depends on the OP; A very quick Google search will reveal DL and a lot of posts...(ps I didnt vote to close but maybe this was the reason..)

Answer (score 1):

[Andrew Ng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng) has a great free course on Convolutional Neural Nets on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/). I recommend watching his videos and defenitely do the coding assignments. it will give you a solid foundation to build on.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would start by learning how to make simple neural networks for image recognition. I started by the [book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Learn-TensorFlow/dp/1491962291) of Aurelien Gueron  which contains a good introduction to tensorflow, a python library for neural networks. There is also a very large literature on the web, have a look at [this](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-Jupyter-Notebooks) which has links to interesting examples of python image recognition, natural language processing, and more problems.

Comment: Thankyou I'll definitely check these out.

Answer (score 0):

The two answers you have been provided make sense and you should definitely take their advice. But, those make for a *long* road ahead of you, so I'm going to go the other way with my answer and give you some things you could be doing in the short-term.

If you are going to decide to dedicate your data science studies to image recognition (and computer vision in general) then you should get used to images as being "data". That can be a tough mental shift for people new to the industry, so you might as well start right away.

Settle on one of the languages you mentioned (I'd recommend Python) and start to manipulate images (any images). Can you take an image apart? Put it back together? Flip it? Color it? Create an augmentation set from them? Transform the data to binary representations? Create single arrays from any number of image sizes? Do you know how to use one of the pre-processing libraries (like the one that ships with Keras) or do  you want to do it on your own?

You should have answers to all of these questions at some point during  your studies and these are certainly things you can start right away.